# Tomcat 9.0: Error deploying web application after install

Tags: java, tomcat9

```
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.837 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.30
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.840 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 7 2019 16:42:04 UTC
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.841 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.30.0
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.841 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.841 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.841 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.841 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.842 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_231-b11
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.842 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.842 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.842 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.843 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\logging.properties
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.843 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.843 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.843 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.844 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.844 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.845 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.849 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.851 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.23] using APR version [1.7.0].
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.854 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.855 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
07-Feb-2020 12:04:55.861 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019]
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.219 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8888"]
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.431 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-9999"]
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.448 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [875] milliseconds
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.491 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.492 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.509 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs]
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.639 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [XMLSchema.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.639 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [datatypes.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.641 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [xml.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.643 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-app_2_2.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.644 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.645 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-app_2_3.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.646 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.647 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [j2ee_web_services_1_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.648 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [j2ee_web_services_client_1_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.649 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-app_2_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.652 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.653 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [j2ee_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.655 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [jsp_2_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.656 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-app_2_5.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.657 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.658 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_5.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.658 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [jsp_2_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.659 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.660 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.664 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-app_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.665 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-fragment_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.666 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-common_3_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.666 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_6.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.667 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [jsp_2_2.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.668 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.669 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.670 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-app_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.671 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-fragment_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.674 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-common_3_1.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.676 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_7.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.676 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [jsp_2_3.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.678 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_web_services_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.680 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_web_services_client_1_4.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.681 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-app_4_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.682 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-fragment_4_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.684 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [web-common_4_0.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.686 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.locationFor The XML schema [javaee_8.xsd] could not be found. This is very likely to break XML validation if XML validation is enabled.
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.758 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1867)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/docs]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:246)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1968)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1128)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 38 more
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.766 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs] has finished in [257] ms
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.768 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\examples]
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.818 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\examples]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1867)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/examples]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:246)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1968)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1128)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 38 more
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.822 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\examples] has finished in [54] ms
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT]
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.963 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1867)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:246)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1968)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1128)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 38 more
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.965 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [20] ms
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.975 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8888"]
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.991 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-9999"]
07-Feb-2020 12:04:56.996 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [545] milliseconds
```

localhost:8080 shows error 404-not found

I just installed tomcat server on my windows 10 pc. Now when i run startup.bat i get this error.
All enviornment variables are set

1. JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231
2. CATALINA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0

windows services list also shows apache tomcat 9 running.

Comment: Got the server working. So the servlet-api.jar in x:/tomcat9/lib folder and x:/jre1.8.0_231/lib/ext folder should be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to generate same error after replacing Tomcat 9 servlate-api to tomcat 8 this show that there version mismatch of servlet-api.

so, either download new tomcat 9 from tomcat site or place correct version servlet-api to path

`x:\apache-tomcat-9.0.30\lib`

Comment: Thanks! copied servlet-api.jar from tomcat folder to jre/lib/ext and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:246)
```

Looks like servlet-api.jar is missing or there is a version mismatch. Try doing a fresh install after removing all directories. Follow https://tomcat.apache.org/